# How to change word color?

Tags: css, colors, dom-manipulation

I want to make it such that when the text in the dom starts loading, text is red.
At random, each letter starts animating a fade/change to blue on first load. Is this possible in CSS3 only or does javascript have to be involved?

Comment: It is possible in CSS under very specific circumstances (you know the length of the text *and* either the text is monospaced or each letter has a wrapper).

Comment: I don't think I would know the length of the text, but it would be a single specific div. Each letter could have its own wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while i think it could be done with CSS i would through the easier way to do it using jQuery:
you need [this plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) and then:

```
$(document).ready(functiom() { //this could be any event
    $('#your_div_id').animate({color: 'blue'});
});
```

your question isn't clear, if you want to get random colors then make an array of colors and randomly select a color, this is what i used for my site:

```
var colors = new Array("blue", "green", "#ffffff", "color4", "color5");
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
```

and in you replace `'blue'` from the pref function with `colors[rand]`

next time, keep your question a little more general so others can use it as well